# Save .org file from org table edit field buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there any command to save the org file from the org table edit field buffer? If not, is there any way to check if the current buffer is an org table edit field buffer?

More details: When I am editing a cell in a org-table in a file, say tmp.org, I can edit the content of that cell in a separate buffer, called "Org Table Edit Field". I want to save the file tmp.org when I am in the buffer "Org Table Edit Field". Here is an example:

[image]

UPDATE (Oct, 2018): I am currently using the following workaround:

```
(defun my-org-save-file()
  (interactive)
  (if org-field-marker
      (progn
        (setq tb-field-current-pos (point))
        (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
        (save-buffer)
        (org-table-edit-field (save-excursion))
        (goto-char tb-field-current-pos)
      )
    (save-buffer)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Would you provide an simple example please? Adding some detail and context to your end goal would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There is `org-save-all-org-buffers` if that is doing what you want. For testing whether you are in a `org-table-edit-field` buffer you can use something like `(if org-field-marker (with-current-buffer  (marker-buffer org-field-marker) (save-buffer)) ...)`.

Comment: `org-field-marker` is what I was looking for...

Comment: Calling `(save-excursion)` without a body form doesn't do anything, I don't think you need it here.